# spring state machine changing to one of two possible states based on action

Tags: spring-statemachine

i'm having trouble configuring my SSM for a very simple scenario:

[image]

the culprit is the 'validation' action that needs to happen when the **log_on** event is fired. i re-read the SSM documentation and am not sure if this is a 'fork', 'guard' or a hierarchical configuration.

the 'action' is performed here:

```
@Component
public class LogonValidationAction implements Action<PickStates, PickEvents> {

Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

volatile int counter = 0;

@Override
public void execute(StateContext<PickStates, PickEvents> context) {
    String eventName = context.getEvent().name();
    logger.info("executing {} for event {}", LogonValidationAction.class.getName(), eventName);

    // basically, if success, send success, if failure, send failure
    // for testing
    if(counter % 2 == 0)
        context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(PickEvents.logon_sucess);
    else
        context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(PickEvents.logon_fail);
}
}
```

i am using 'counter' in my test to direct the flow to either 'failure' (logged_off state remains) or 'success' (state changes to logged_on).

here's the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class Config extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<PickStates, PickEvents>{

@Autowired
StateMachineListener stateMachineListener;

@Autowired
LogonValidationAction logonValidationAction;

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<PickStates, PickEvents> states) throws Exception {
    states
        .withStates()
        .initial(PickStates.logged_off)
        .state(PickStates.logged_on)
        .states(EnumSet.allOf(PickStates.class));
}

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<PickStates, PickEvents> transitions) throws Exception {
    transitions
        .withExternal()
        .source(PickStates.logged_off)
        .target(PickStates.logged_on)
        .event(PickEvents.log_on)
        .action(logonValidationAction)
        .and()
        .withExternal()
        .source(PickStates.logged_on)
        .target(PickStates.logged_off)
        .event(PickEvents.log_off);
}

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<PickStates, PickEvents> config) throws Exception {
    config
        .withConfiguration()
        .autoStartup(true)
        .listener(stateMachineListener);
}
}
```

this is the failing test (expecting 'logged_off' when the action fires the logon_fail event):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class EzpickStateMachineTest {

Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

@Autowired
StateMachineFactory<PickStates, PickEvents> stateMachineFactory;

// for testing so can toggle success/failure when logging in
@Autowired
LogonValidationAction logonValidationAction;

@Test
public void failLogon() throws Exception {
    StateMachine<PickStates, PickEvents> stateMachine = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine();

    stateMachine.start();

    // when sm starts, state is 'logged_off'
    assertThat(stateMachine.getState().getId().name(), is(PickStates.logged_off.name()));

    // odd numbers fire 'failure' event
    logonValidationAction.setCounter(1);

    stateMachine.sendEvent(PickEvents.log_on);

    // if logon fails, state is 'logged_off'
    assertThat(stateMachine.getState().getId().name(), is(PickStates.logged_off.name()));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From action you try to send either `logon_sucess` or `logon_fail` but in machine configuration you haven't defined any transitions for those events so machine would not do anything.

Other notes, don't store `counter` in action bean, use machine extended state variables for it as then it becomes visible to every component using machine or `StateContext`.

When that `counter` is available in extended state, you can i.e. create an anonymous transition with a guard which uses that counter from extended state. One other possibility is to use choice pseudostate and guards to make a choice between target states. Your use of counter is exactly what wiki mention about in its extended state section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Extended_states

Comment: "From action you try to send either logon_sucess or logon_fail but in machine configuration you haven't defined any transitions for those events so machine would not do anything."
can you provide an example of how to do this ... this was the main part of my question.

thanks for the 'counter' suggestion. i'll look into it b/c do not understand what you're recommending

Comment: i still did not get a usable response from you regarding the configuration, please provide an example configuration

Comment: You defined `event(PickEvents.log_on)` and `event(PickEvents.log_off)` and use those in a test. Those are only events you associated with transitions. Then from action you send `PickEvents.logon_sucess` which don't have transition associated so machine will not do anything. Not sure how else I'd describe what's missing. (unless your code snippet is incomplete)